# How to use SqlDataReader object to plot Y axis on a chart using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I want to use SQlDatareader object to plot Y Axis on my chart. The column has int values in it. I am generating the chart through code behind. Any help would be appreciated as I am real close to my target but stuck here only. Below is my code. I am actually unable to convert the Type dr to array.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select items from student_info", conn);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {


        int[] yValues = { //Here I want the dr };
        string[] xValues = { "Coke", "Pepsi","Coffee"};

        Chart chart = new Chart();

        Series series = new Series("Default");
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

        chart.Series.Add(series);

        ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
        Axis yAxis = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.Y);
        Axis xAxis = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.X);

        chart.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

        chart.Width = new Unit(500, System.Web.UI.WebControls.UnitType.Pixel);
        chart.Height = new Unit(200, System.Web.UI.WebControls.UnitType.Pixel);
        string filename = "C:\\check\\Chart.png";
        chart.SaveImage(filename, ChartImageFormat.Png);

        Panel1.Controls.Add(chart);
    }
```

Comment: Do you really want to add a Chart for every item even if you always have the same xValues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the type `dr = DataRow` returns, as the name already says, a `ROW`. So it returns a single value.

If you want to add many values to the array, and you want to use the values from the database, you need to create an array and fill it with the results of the DataRows while looping through the values you get from the query.

But I would suggest you to rather use a [List<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) than an array for this, and then use the methode [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx).

Examplecode:

```
List<int> xValues = new List<int>();    

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if(dr.HasRows) //Check if datareader is not null, allways do this.

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        int number;
        bool result = Int32.TryParse(dr["items"], out number);
        if (result) //check if its really a number
        {
            xValues.Add(number);         
        }
        else
        {
            number = 0; //no number, so just assign 0 to the list
            xValues.Add(number);
        }
     }
```

And then if you add the xValues and yValues:

```
chart.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues.ToArray(), yValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

First create the array from sqldatareader. Then use it to generate the chart.
you have also place the chart code inside the while loop. which will create a chart and add it to the panel for each row in student_info table. So place you chart code outside the while loop.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select items from student_info", conn);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0])); //getting all values in a List
}

int[] yValues = list.ToArray<int>(); //create your array here then use it
string[] xValues = { "Coke", "Pepsi","Coffee"};

Chart chart = new Chart();

Series series = new Series("Default");
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

chart.Series.Add(series);

ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
Axis yAxis = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.Y);
Axis xAxis = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.X);

chart.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

chart.Width = new Unit(500, System.Web.UI.WebControls.UnitType.Pixel);
chart.Height = new Unit(200, System.Web.UI.WebControls.UnitType.Pixel);
string filename = "C:\\check\\Chart.png";
chart.SaveImage(filename, ChartImageFormat.Png);

Panel1.Controls.Add(chart);
```